# how to avoid naming conflict with VSConstants.S_OK Field?

Tags: c++, enums, c++-cli, native, managed

Here is the scenario:

I have WSCF Blue generated C# Web Service client that i have to call from C. I do it with C++ CLI "bridge". In C# web service client I have

```
namespace MyCompany.Product.ExternalPlan.Client
{
    public enum TMsgStatus
    {
        S_OK,
        //...
        E_ERROR,
    }
```

which is fine.

The C++ CLI project does something like this (this is not in any namespace!!):

```
try 
{
    EPClient::Client^ client = gcnew EPClient::Client();
    m_ResponseHeader = client->CreateExternalProject(n_Project->Id, m_ProjectData,     m_NameValuePairs,    // in 
                                    m_PlanAndWorksExternal, ConvertNativeToManaged(n_UserName),         // in 
                                    m_ProjectRet, m_PlanAndWorksRet);                                   // out
}
catch (Exception ^ e)
{
    // ...
    return -1;
}

if (m_ResponseHeader->Status == MyCompany::Product::ExternalPlan::Client::TMsgStatus::S_OK)
{
    ConvertManagedToNative(n_ProjectRet, m_ProjectRet);
}
```

Now if I change S_OK in the if-statement above to E_ERROR it's OK. I read that in C++ enums are global so I think that's the reason it's mixed with this VS thing.  I know almost nothing about C++ programming. C++ code is called from C and I have similar example that has no namespace. I don't think it even matters because i'm refering to S_OK with full namespace thing.

Thanks & Best Regards! -matti

Comment: In C++ 11 you can create non-global enum (google `enum class`, for example, http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html). Also, if you still experience problems with enums, try to use direct `integer` value instead of `S_OK` in your code as a very quick (may be not the best) solution.

Comment: S_OK is a *macro* that appears in Windows SDK #include files.  The pre-processor translates it to ((HRESULT)0).  It is important in COM code.  If renaming it in the C# source is a problem then #undef is a valid workaround.  As long as you don't write any COM code anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's more a problem of `#define` than namespaces. Try `#undef S_OK` before your code that uses it.